# Prevent NVelocity from displaying Tokens

Tags: asp.net, velocity, nvelocity

I have the following piece of code in my template that uses NVelocity to process form data:

```
$PartnerProfile.Nvalue("Name")
```

In case the *Nvalue* method doesn't return any value, I want NVelocity to display nothing. But it rather outputs the code, i.e. 
**"Lorem ipsum dolor sit *$PartnerProfile.Nvalue("Name")* amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt"**

How can I prevent that code to be displayed in my output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is very simple. I just need to add the character '!' to the beginning of the token.
Like this:

```
$!PartnerProfile.Nvalue("Name")
```

The output in case there's no value for the indicated parameter will be empty.

**"Lorem ipsum dolor sit *$PartnerProfile.Nvalue("Name")* amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt"**

will be this -->

**"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt"**